# angular JS mock json unit testing

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

```
var app= angular.module('app', []);
```

below is my factory method that will get the data from the sample.json

```
app.factory('factoryGetJSONFile', function($http) {
  return {
    getMyData: function(done) {
      $http.get('mock/sample.json')
      .success(function(data) {
        done(data);
      })
      .error(function(error) {
        alert('An error occured whilst trying to retrieve your data');
      });
    }
  }
});
```

below is my controller. I can able to access the service data in my controller

```
app.controller('homeController', ['$scope', 'factoryGetJSONFile', function ($scope, factoryGetJSONFile) {

    factoryGetJSONFile.getMyData(function (data) {
        $scope.name = data.projectDetails.name;
        $scope.duration = data.projectDetails.duration;
        console.log($scope.name+ " and duration is " + $scope.duration);
    });

}]);
```

Below is my sample.json

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "projectDetails": {
        "name": "Project Name",
        "duration": "4 Months",
        "business_place": "Dummy address"
    }
}
```

How to write the unit test cases for the above get service. I would like to test projectDetails.name in my test cases.

Comment: You can find it here [link](http://jsfiddle.net/seshuggina/5u7L8mou/2/)

http://jsfiddle.net/seshuggina/5u7L8mou/2/

Answer (score 1):

To mock http responses you can use the [$httpbackend](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend) service. For example, if you want to test the `getMyData` method of the object created by your factory, you'd do something like:

```
var $httpbackend,
factoryGetJSONFile;

var sample.json = // Your sample JSON
var getUrl = 'mock/sample.json';

beforeEach(inject(function(_$httpbackend_, _factoryGetJSONFile_) {
    // Load app
    module('app');
    // Make services available in tests
    $httpbackend = _$httpbackend_;
    factoryGetJSONFile = _factoryGetJSONFile;

    // Mock the server's response
    $httpbackend.when('GET', getUrl).
        respond(sample.json);

}));

It('factoryGetJSONFile.getMyData should make correct GET request', function() {
    // Call your services method and flush $httpbackend so the mock response is sent
    var response = factoryGetJSONFile.getMyData();
    $httpBackend.flush();

    expect(response).toEqual(jasmine.objectContaining(sample.json));
});
```

Comment: its not working.. its throwing following error

factoryGetJSONFile.getMyData should make correct GET request

Comment: What error is it throwing? What you gave is just the description of the test. You need ngMocks installed to use $httpbackend so check that `angular-mocks.js` is included in your karma.conf.js file.

Comment: I have included angular-mock.js.

Expected undefined to equal Object({ status: 200, projectDetails: Object({ name: 'Project Name', duration: '4 Months', business_place: 'some address' }) }).

Comment: You have to load your app in the unit tests; I forgot to put that in.  I'll update my answer. If it still doesn't work after that please upload your tests somewhere and I'll look at them.